# C union - please explain

Tags: c, sdl-2

As far as I understand a **union** in C can hold only 1 value at a time and I don't really understand how this code in C makes sense since **event.window** cannot be populated at the same time as **event.type**?

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
switch(event.type)
{
case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
    switch(event.window.event)
```

The event is defined as:

```
typedef union SDL_Event
{
    Uint32 type;                    /**< Event type, shared with all events */
    SDL_CommonEvent common;         /**< Common event data */
    SDL_WindowEvent window;         /**< Window event data */
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;          /**< Keyboard event data */
    SDL_TextEditingEvent edit;      /**< Text editing event data */
    SDL_TextInputEvent text;        /**< Text input event data */
    SDL_MouseMotionEvent motion;    /**< Mouse motion event data */
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent button;    /**< Mouse button event data */
    SDL_MouseWheelEvent wheel;      /**< Mouse wheel event data */
    SDL_JoyAxisEvent jaxis;         /**< Joystick axis event data */
    SDL_JoyBallEvent jball;         /**< Joystick ball event data */
    SDL_JoyHatEvent jhat;           /**< Joystick hat event data */
    SDL_JoyButtonEvent jbutton;     /**< Joystick button event data */
    SDL_JoyDeviceEvent jdevice;     /**< Joystick device change event data */
    SDL_ControllerAxisEvent caxis;      /**< Game Controller axis event data */
    SDL_ControllerButtonEvent cbutton;  /**< Game Controller button event data */
    SDL_ControllerDeviceEvent cdevice;  /**< Game Controller device event data */
    SDL_QuitEvent quit;             /**< Quit request event data */
    SDL_UserEvent user;             /**< Custom event data */
    SDL_SysWMEvent syswm;           /**< System dependent window event data */
    SDL_TouchFingerEvent tfinger;   /**< Touch finger event data */
    SDL_MultiGestureEvent mgesture; /**< Gesture event data */
    SDL_DollarGestureEvent dgesture; /**< Gesture event data */
    SDL_DropEvent drop;             /**< Drag and drop event data */

    /* This is necessary for ABI compatibility between Visual C++ and GCC
       Visual C++ will respect the push pack pragma and use 52 bytes for
       this structure, and GCC will use the alignment of the largest datatype
       within the union, which is 8 bytes.

       So... we'll add padding to force the size to be 56 bytes for both.
    */
    Uint8 padding[56];
} SDL_Event;
```

Comment: Other union event begins with an `Uint32 type;`

Comment: The `union` is set of different "viewpoints" of the same binary data. You can assign all possible members of union but each next assignment will overwrite the value stored before.

Comment: The C++ tag is probably wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every aggregate (`struct`s probably) member `SDL_CommonEvent common;`, `SDL_WindowEvent window;`,  `SDL_KeyboardEvent key;` etc... of the `union SDL_Event` is starting with some `Uint32`  field giving the `type` and that common `type` field has the same address and size in every union member.

So while indeed a union carries only one field at once in memory (in other words, all union members have the same address), each of them starts with a `type` and the `event.type` makes sense; it fetches that `type`.

Such an idiom is a common way in C to implement [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Answer (score 4):

Every member of the `SDL_Event` union starts with the same two members, `Uint32 type` and `Uint32 timestamp`. The C standard specifically says that if a union is currently holding a value of one struct type, but read as another struct type whose first members match the other struct type, it's okay to read those matching members.

Answer (score 2):

All other `SDL_X` types all begin with a type of 32 bits. In fact, they all seem to include the fields in `SDL_CommonEvent` at the beginning. This is to facilitate accesing common elements to all sub-structures. Then, by `event.common.x` you can access all the common elements without having to differentiate the exact type of event.